# Possible to lookup ordered row from XML variable using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We want to take an existing XML data set, build a rowset, and lookup the ordered rows contained within that rowset. Is it possible to execute an "LookupOrderedRow" function that references the rowset? Can we just replace the data extension portion of the lookup with the rowset variable to achieve this?

@xml variable contains xml file values

```
Set @rowset = BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, "//Record", 1)
Set @familyid = Field(Row(@rowset, 1), 'FamilyID_att')
Set @GroupRecords = LookupOrderedRows(@rowset,0,"AppointmentDateTime","FamilyID",@familyid)
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I have not been able to test as of yet because the client has not configured the API fully that will pass through the XML file to our "xml" variable

Comment: It would certainly be easy to test since you could just build an XML string manually, e.g. `set @xml = "<person><name>John Doe</name><familyID>1234</familyID></person>"`

Comment: We are using a slightly different format
<Message>
<HOHRecord HOHID=’49’ FamilyId=’123456’ ClinicID=’41’></HOHRecord>
<PatientRecord FamilyId=’123456’ PatientID='50' LastName='Jones' FirstName='William' AppointmentDateTime='' AppointmentTypeCode='' AppointmentSubTypeCode='' </ PatientRecord >
<PatientRecord FamilyId=’123456’ PatientID='55' LastName='Jones' FirstName='Alison' AppointmentDateTime='12/5/2014 10:45:00' AppointmentTypeCode='1' AppointmentSubTypeCode='' </PatientRecord >
</Message>